# high straight vs low straight/flush

Tags: betting-strategy

The table was a bit loose.

BB is 2000 and I had 45000 and the opponent 35000.

I was under the gun with suited 78.

I limped in and no one raised but got some calls.

The flop came 456 rainbow. SB and BB checked so I bet a small to get calls. Everyone folded to the button, who called.

The turn came 3h (second heart on the board) and I bet again and the button raised. I went all in and he called.

The river came another heart and he made flush with 73 hearts.

Maybe I should have bet more after the flop but I thought I was pretty safe to say I had the strongest hand.

Would you have done any differently after the flop or the turn?

Comment: how many players at the table?  cash?  73 suited seems really loose to me, even on the button.

Comment: If the turn was 3h and this was the 2nd heart on board, Villain cannot have won with a flush with 73, as they'd need the 3h in their hand...

Comment: @Michael unlikely it was cash given the 2k BB and short stacks involved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you call this high straight verses low strait/flush.  There is no strait/flush on the board.  Villain and board with 3 hearts is questionable.

78 suited is best with a multiple players and get in cheap.  You are looking for 2 pair or better on the flop and you will flop that about 5.6% of the time.

Limp 78s UTG short stacked is marginal but I am OK with it. You got what you needed with some calls and no raise.

You flopped the nuts with no flush draw. Yes value bet small. A second heart on turn turn yes value bet, he raised, you pushed.  You got it all in with the nuts.  At this point the only hand that can beat you is flush draw. You are a 4:1 favorite.  Runner runner is a bad beat.

Answer (score 0):

> The flop came 456 rainbow. SB and BB checked so I bet a small to get calls.

Overlooking the question you asked for now (I will come back to it in a moment), why do you feel betting small here is the way to go?  Or rather, what hands do you think they're checking with?  I would say that gutshots with an overcard and flush draws are all wanting to check, so why not bet?  Players at this level are easy:  If you have a good hand you want to maximise your value.  If you'd bet big here then you'd have gotten more value.

As it's played you did the right thing, you got it in with the best hand so.  You cannot try to think "oh how could I get away?" if you get away from a flopped straight at these levels then you'll lose money in the long run.  You made the right play, pat yourself on the back and give yourself some credit for making the right decision.  If they didn't get lucky sometimes then they wouldn't play.